# Yii CListView Search with Subqueries

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am using a CListView to display my data on a page. I have a textbox for searching keywords in the query.

In my query where I build my CActiveDataProvider I have some subqueries. For Example:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('
    Lessons.id,
    Lessons.name,
    (SELECT
        COALESCE(CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", u.last_name), last_name, first_name)
    FROM
        users AS u
    WHERE
        u.user_token = Lessons.instructor_id
    ) as instructor_name
');
```

My model for the above query does have a class variable called $instructor_name.

When I enter data into the textbox I then run this piece of code to join another table for searching.

```
if ( !empty($query) ) {
    $criteria->with = array('packages');
    $criteria->compare( 'packages.contents', $query, true);
    $criteria->together = true;
}
```

The results when running a search query do not return the instructor_name data from the subquery.

Any ideas on what is happening here to prevent my subquery data from loading? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a more CActiveRecord way (and get the results your looking for), try the following:

1 - Add instructor relation to Lesson model that references the User table (so now you will be able to do $lesson->instructor)

```
'instructor'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'instructor_id'),
```

2 - Add a column/expression into the select clause in your Lesson::search() method that represents the concatenated instructor_name  - something like:

```
$criteria->select = array('
Lessons.id,
Lessons.name,
COALESCE(CONCAT(instructor.first_name, " ", instructor.last_name), last_name, first_name) AS instructor_name
...etc
```

3 - Add instructor to the "with" part of the search criteria so that the instructor info is joined into the query

```
$criteria->with = array('packages', 'instructor');
```

Comment: What I seem to find is when I add a value to the with part of the search criteria.

e.g.
`$criteria->with = array('instructor');`

My SQL query that runs does not factor in the original select value. Thus erasing the subquery to use Yii defaults.

Comment: Doing it this way, you should not need a subquery, as the columns are joined in - and then a formula is used to calculate the instructor_name field.